# Multiple KeyBinding like Visual Studio in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

I have tried to read many posts on StackOverflow about how to implement the KeyBinding like Visual Studio **Ctrl+Shift+ A** or **Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C**  but no luck

I have found [this](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/03/multikeygesture.html) article on on blogspot regarding Multiple Keybinding  but it makes multiple gesture like **Ctrl + A,B**

Is it possible to make a Keybinding that flexible like (VS Studio) through XAML Syantax.

Comment: What do you mean by that comma in `Ctrl+A,B` ... does it mean a command that executes when you press either Ctrl+A or Ctrl+B? Or does it say the command should execute when you press Ctrl+AB? For multiple modifiers like "Ctrl+Shift+..." the source code posted as part of the "article" that you have provided, can be easily used \ modified isn it?

Comment: Yes i tried to make an array for Modifiers but then it doesent work.
And Ctrl + A,B means presseing Ctrl and then pressing A and then B

Comment: @AngelWPF I currently dont have acces to Myremote system i'll get back to you with waht i have tried (also i currently dont have acces to blogspot :))

Comment: The term is called a "chord" btw, might help in future searches.  You probably need to create a command binding that can be bound to many key combinations that waits for a full chord before executing.  Nothing in the framework for this.

Answer (score 3):

Sequence key combo's like VS has are not natively part of WPF and most other UI frameworks.  The reason being that such combos hail from text editors of the Jurassic era and survive only in a few modern contexts where users of said era still survive and even thrive.  ;-)

You should be able to provide your own handling mechanisms for this in a fairly straight forward manner:

- Build a mechanism to parse and represent these combos.
- Provide key handling logic that recognizes the beginning of the sequence and goes into compound key mode
- Provide a cue to the user when in combo mode
- Adapt your key handling when in combo mode

Ideally you'll associate these combos command so there is no disparity between singles and combos.

Comment: I'd +10 for the 'jurassic' word, I laughed so hard :) don't you dare do that again! :P

Answer (score 0):

```
    <KeyBinding x:Name="mykeybinding" Gesture="CTRL+E" Key="P" 
                Command="commandname"/>
```

Seems to be working ok for me you have to press ctrl+E+P to execute command.

Based on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx